# Provider not notified from cookbook_file

Tags: chef-infra

I'm working on an ssl provider using Vagrant (1.0.5) and chef-solo (10.12.0)

I have my provider, called ssl within a cookbook called gtm_cq, I define it as such in my cookbook's default recipe:

```
gtm_cq_ssl "author" do
    # attributes will come later
end
```

I then have my cookbook_file like below that should notify my ssl provider's `import` action  once it pushes the cert up to the server:

```
cookbook_file "#{node[:cq][:ssl][:author_cert_location]}/foo.cer" do
    source "foo.cer"
    owner "crx"
    group "root"
    mode "0644"
    notifies :import, resources(:gtm_cq_ssl => "author")
end
```

When I run this, the foo.cer gets pushed up as expected, but the `import` action of my ssl provider is never called. The most I see of any reference is these couple of lines in the log (removed log headers):

```
.. cookbook_file[/opt/cq5/author/foo.cer] sending import action to gtm_cq_ssl[author] (delayed)
.. Processing gtm_cq_ssl[author] action import (gtm_cq::author line 34)
```

There's a large very obvious log statement as well as the use of another cookbook_file for a test file to push something up to the server. No log statement, no test file pushed. I'm certain too that the foo.cer file is removed from the server before each test.

I found that if I edit my notifies line like so with `:immediately`

```
notifies :import, resources(:gtm_cq_ssl => "author"), :immediately
```

It seems to work. And I suppose this is ok in my particular case, but it would seem something is not right if that's the only way I can call my provider.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

edit:

So after further investigation, it turns out my provider does get called, but my cookbook_file  call within my provider is never called. The logs have no reference to it. Here's my provider:

```
action :import do

    Chef::Log.info "This is my LOG!!!!!!!!!!"
    cookbook_file "/opt/cq5/worked.dat" do
        source "worked.dat"
        cookbook "gtm_cq"
        owner "crx"
        group "root"
        mode "0644"
    end

end
```

and here's the logging where my log statement appears, but nothing about the `worked.dat` cookbook file being executed"

```
INFO: cookbook_file[/opt/cq5/author/nike.cer] sending import action to gtm_cq_ssl[author] (delayed)
INFO: Processing gtm_cq_ssl[author] action import (gtm_cq::author line 15)
INFO: This is my puts you PUTZ!!!!!!!!!!
INFO: template[/etc/httpd/conf/cq-farms/farm_10author.any] sending restart action to service[apache2] (delayed)
INFO: Processing service[apache2] action restart (apache2::default line 217)
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Resources that receive a "delayed" notification (i.e. without :immediately) are executed at the end of the Chef run.

I think at that point it may be too late for something like the `cookbook_file` you have inside :import.

You could try something like this:

```
action :import do
    Chef::Log.info "This is my LOG!!!!!!!!!!"
    cookbook_file "/opt/cq5/worked.dat" do
        source "worked.dat"
        cookbook "gtm_cq"
        owner "crx"
        group "root"
        mode "0644"
        action :nothing      # <— add this
     end.run_action(:create) # <- change this
end
```

This will run that resource as soon as the :import action is called instead of queueing it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax should be

```
notifies :import, "gtm_cq_ssl[author]", :immediately
```